# WIX / MSI value not removed

Tags: windows, wix, installation, windows-installer

I'm using wix 3.8 to build an installer. I have a custom property like this:

```
<Property Id="FOO" Value="1234" />
```

which I'm using to set a custom registry value:

```
<RegistryKey Id='ID1' Root='HKLM' Key='Software\ACME\Bar' Action='create'>
...
  <RegistryValue Type='binary' Name='FooBinary' Value='[FOO]'/>
...
```

It all works fine but when I uninstall the package, FooBinary stays in the registry. This only happens if I use a custom property. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: With just that source, hard to say. The component guid may once (or now) have been made permanent; maybe the guid isn't unique and is shared with something else.

Comment: @PhilDW: it is unique. I don't have time to strip down to the minimal error + Buzka91's answer did it for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Acording to documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/registrykey.html) you can add *ForceDeleteOnUninstall* attribute with value *yes* to your *RegistryKey* element.

> Set this attribute to 'yes' to remove the key with all its values and
>   subkeys when the parent component is uninstalled. Note that this value
>   is useful only if your program creates additional values or subkeys
>   under this key and you want an uninstall to remove them. MSI already
>   removes all values and subkeys that it creates, so this option just
>   adds additional overhead to uninstall. The default is "no".

Comment: Probably not an ideal solution but works for my needs. Thanks.